# Flexbox inside list item doesn't align to the top of the list item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Putting a flexbox inside of a list item is causing the content to get pushed down by what appears to be a full line height.

I've been playing around with different CSS properties, such as giving the flexbox `margin-top: 0`, its children `margin-top:0`, adding `flex-wrap` to the flexbox, etc. No dice!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>world</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENavrK)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems due to the `::marker` pseudo-element.

I don't know exactly what should happen because this is an overlap of various specs

- [CSS Display 3 - the `list-item` keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#list-items)
- [CSS Pseudo-Elements 4 - the `::marker` pseudo-element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#marker-pseudo)
- [CSS Lists and Counters 3 - The ::marker pseudo-element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#marker-pseudo)

And it's problematic because they are proposals not ready for implementation. See for example the warning in [CSS Lists 3 - Positioning Markers](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#positioning-markers), which is also relevant in this issue:

> This section is not ready for implementation. It is an unreviewed
>   rough draft that hasn’t even been properly checked for
>   Web-compatibility. Feel free to send feedback, but DON’T USE THIS PART
>   OF THE SPEC.

The following is my guess of how Chrome handles markers under the hood.

First, let's use the simpler `list-style-position: inside` on the list item, and let it contain a block:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Hello<br />world</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Chrome displays it like this:

[image]

Note the marker overlaps the div, but shrinks its first line box. This behavior is typical of floats!

A float should not overlap a formatting context root. For example, `display: inline-block` establishes a block formatting context.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Hello<br />world</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

So like a float, the marker pushes it to the right, to prevent overlapping.

But note the marker is vertically aligned. And establishing a block formatting context with `overflow: hidden` does not prevent overlapping.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Hello<br />world</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So it has some float-like behaviors, but it's not a float.

My guess is that Chrome keeps iterating the first box in the list item, then the first box inside it, and so on, until the first box is no longer a block. Then it inserts the marker just before it, displayed inline-level (maybe `inline-block`). Something like this:

```
var deepestFirstBlock,
    child = listItem;
do {
  deepestFirstBlock = child;
  child = deepestFirstBlock.firstBoxChild;
} while (child.style.display == 'block');
deepestFirstBlock.insertBefore(marker, deepestFirstBlock.firstBoxChild);
```

It's not exactly that, because if the `direction` of the deepest first block is right-to-left, then the marker is inserted after the last box of the first line.

Therefore, as noticed by Michael_B, when you style the inner container with `display: inline-flex` there is no empty space. That's because the marker is inserted before it, and since both are inline-level they appear side by side.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Hello<br />world</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

But a `display: flex` container is block-level. So it is forced to go to the next line. The empty space is then the marker, which occupies the first line box.

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Hello<br />world</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

This does not happen with `display: block`, which is also block-level, because the marker is inserted inside it. I guess the marker is not inserted inside a block-level flex container because then it would become a flex item and it could produce a bizarre layout.

When you use the initial `list-style-position: outside`, it seems Chrome just applies some kind of negative horizontal margin to the marker, so that the following box (which was the first one before inserting the marker) becomes aligned at the left of the container like before inserting the marker. Maybe the marker is also floated, since floated contents inside the list-item are no longer able to appear at its left.

However, this negative margin won't allow the block-level flex container to go up. That's why the space remains, even though the marker is no longer in there.

Note this contradicts the current unreviewed rough draft not ready for implementation, which says markers with `list-style-position: outside` should have `position: marker`, and

> An element with [`position: marker`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#position-marker) counts as [absolutely positioned](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned).

Absolutely positioned elements are taken out-of-flow and overlap following elements, so the flex container should me moved to the top.

Firefox seems to do something simpler. With `list-style-position: inside`, it just inserts the marker as the first (inline-level) box of the list-item. It doesn't attempt to iterate blocks to insert the marker at the deepest possible level.

However, with `list-style-position: outside`, it probably takes the marker out-of-flow, just like the draft says. That's why you don't see the space in Firefox.

Comment: I think this is the best possible explanation considering the available information. Thank you. (I'm going to let the bounty run its course, but will be very surprised if a better answer gets posted.)

Comment: Yes, maybe the bounty will attract someone who has looked at the code and can clarify what exactly browsers do. But not sure if there are many people like that which are active in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

### Solutions

If you switch `.wrapper` from `display: flex` to `inline-flex`, the issue is resolved ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbWRyo)).

If you set `list-style-type` to `none`, the issue is resolved (credit [@Ricky_Ruiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4305494/ricky-ruiz) in the comments) ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpPvzE)).

### Browser Behavior

The problem exists in Chrome, Edge and IE11. The original code works fine in Firefox and Safari.

### Explanation

I'm currently not sure what's causing the behavior.

For some reason (apparently the marker), the top section of the `li` is off-limits. The parent is not allowing the children to access the area.

(***UPDATE:*** *A detailed explanation has been provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456240/3597276).*)

In testing...

- I removed `padding` and `margin` from `ul` and descendants. It didn't help.
- I played with `line-height` and `vertical-align`. Also didn't help.

By setting an equal height to all elements, it's clear that something is forcing the flex container to render lower than expected, and overflow the parent.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>hello</div>
      <div>world</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoNZXQ)

Comment: Kudos for awarding rep on this, M. Since the OP seems non-responsive, could you please notify readers about the existence of the one you awarded? I almost missed it. Btw, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: block` to the `li` style properties resolves this. By default, the user agent styles will set `li` elements to display as `list-item`. The [flexbox specifications do not account for this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), instead specifying behavior for only block, inline, and inline-block elements (as well as table-cell elements, which trigger block-level flex items).

Comment: Except it works with `display: list-item` on the parent if the child is `display: inline-flex`.