# Flexbox puts empty line inside <li> in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have following HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <div>Giraffe</div>
            <div>Lion</div>
            <div>Koala Bear</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

For some reason, Google Chrome puts empty line above the animals, like this:

```
1.
   GiraffeLionKoala Bear
```

Why is that and how to prevent it? It behaves like this even if I set the width manually.

Tested on Chrome, FF and Safari. Only Google Chrome is the problem.

Comment: Whoah this is awesome, why the hell is it doing that? Another good question is why is there a div with 3 div's inside an li? Wouldn't you just want to separate the items into 3 li's instead? Either way I'm going to try and fix it

Comment: @StefanBob This is just the part of my HTML, it makes sense in entire context :) This flexbox includes some text and icons and is just the header of each `<li>`.

Comment: I actually took a stab at this problem a few months ago. Not a simple matter. Had to put a bounty on the question. The explanation is surprisingly complex. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your question has already been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413013/flexbox-inside-list-item-doesnt-align-to-the-top-of-the-list-item).

***Very important:*** The dupe question has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456240/1891677) containing a full explanation on the cause (`::marker`), ***below*** the accepted answer.

Since the accepted answer doesn't currently seem to solve your problem (make the flex expand the full width of the `<li>` element). And the explanation doesn't seem to do it either, here's a practical solution:

```
display: inline-flex;
width: 100%;
```

```css
ol li .li-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="li-flex">
            <div>Giraffe</div>
            <div>Lion</div>
            <div>Koala Bear</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please read my question again.

Comment: I did. I'll update with an example. Tell me if it's not what you want and why it's not (maybe I don't understand correctly the desired behavior). I'll add some additional ***reset*** CSS, to override default browser styles.

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the numbering. The thing is the empty line above the content, like I presented in the preview. Animals are not in line with the numbering.

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug in Chrome. On trying to find a workaround (`display:inline-flex` is not good, because it doesn't span the entire `<li>`) I also discovered your question is [a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413013/flexbox-inside-list-item-doesnt-align-to-the-top-of-the-list-item). However, there's no good answer there (none that behaves like a proper `display:flex` in `<li>`.

Comment: Actually, the explanation is in the answer ***below*** the accepted one in the dupe question. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40456240/1891677)! Based on this, I've cast my vote for dupe. Although I don't like the other question currently has an accepted answer which only says "I don't know why", and has below another one explaining it.

Comment: This workaround of `inline-flex` with full width seems like the best solution until Google Chrome gets a bit smarter about this. Thank you for pointing out to this `::marker` issue.

Comment: I almost missed it. Just scrolled out of reflex, while thinking about possible solutions, causes, workarounds. And than I saw it. Bam! :)

Comment: What a pleasant coinsidence then :)

Answer (score 0):

change `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex;`.

Comment: But it is supposed to be `flex`, not `inline-flex`. I have other elements there too. And yes, I could wrap `inline-flex` in `<div>`, but I prefer to know what is going on :)

Comment: so maybe use `float: left`?

Comment: You know, I can think of 100 workarounds, but I'm curious why it's happening and some clean fix. Float is not really meant for this purpose.