# List item alignment problem with flexbox in IE 11 and Edge

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I've created an ordered list of questions, with the option to edit or delete each one. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and flexboxes to design my website. The list looks great on Firefox and Chrome, but when I switch to IE11 or Edge, there's some strange top padding that I can't seem to get rid of unless I stop using flexboxes in the list.

**This is what my list looks like in Firefox and Chrome**

[image: Image of an ordered list]

**This is what my list looks like in IE11 and Edge**

[image: Image of the same ordered list]

Here's a JSFiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/0g7mpovu

```
<ol class="mb-0">
  <li class="px-3 py-1">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-self-center flex-grow-1 w-100">
        How would you describe a surplus in your own words?
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" title="Actions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h text-muted"></i>
          </button>

          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="px-3 py-1">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-self-center flex-grow-1 w-100">
        What is a fiscal budget?
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" title="Actions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h text-muted"></i>
          </button>

          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

How can I make my list look the same on all browsers? I am open to changing this to a table or other element if needed, but I would still like to display the numbers.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug.

Here's a possible fix:

Instead of using a block-level flex container (`display: flex`), use an inline-level container (`display: inline-flex`) with full width added (`width: 100%`).

Add this to your code:

```
.d-flex {
   display: inline-flex;
   width: 100%;
}
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa6wv2ro/)

I'm thinking this bug is related to the post below. But since the problem here is confined to IE11 and Edge, and the problem there involves Chrome, I didn't close this post as a duplicate.

- [Flexbox inside list item doesn't align to the top of the list item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40413013/3597276)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a wonderful, simple fix. I didn't use your CSS because `d-flex` is a Bootstrap 4 class that I don't think is wise to override. Instead, I changed the first child div of the `<li>` from `<div class="d-flex">` to `<div class="d-inline-flex w-100">`. Here's my updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLvxa57y/

Comment: Yes, the Bootstrap classes are the wiser choice. I posted the plain CSS for clarity and demo purposes.